# Impractical jokers ever gotten into serious trouble?

Tags: impractical-jokers

Have the guys from the show Impractical Jokers gotten into any major trouble because of the nature of their show?

Eg: have they been physically assaulted or has anyone thrown a law suit on them?

Answer (score 3):

From the trivia on [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2100976/trivia?ref_=tt_ql_2)

> Several pranks have gotten the jokers in trouble with the police. For instance, Murr using a stranger's camera to take a picture of his genitals and Joe standing over strangers at a beach and using his crotch to invade their personal space.
>
> In a Reddit AMA, Sal said he has been physically assaulted two times: A woman slapped him for telling her that her baby was ugly and a war vet choked him for cutting in line.