# Have any fights happened because of the joking on Impractical Jokers

Tags: impractical-jokers

I love the show, and was just wondering if any of the guys have gotten into a fight because of their awesome sense of humor.

Comment: I've always had that doubt too. Not everyone would take it easy ! But this may answer your question maybe ? http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/31868/impractical-jokers-ever-gotten-into-serious-trouble